# Accessing a hashmap as an attribute of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an instance of an object that is created like this:

```
Example.create(:attrib0 => {
  :attrib1 => value,
  :attrib2 => [
    {:attrib3 => value},
    {:attrib4 => value}
    ]
})
```

How can I access `:attrib4`?

Comment: not clear your question

Comment: Will the sub-hashes in `:attrib2` ever change their order? Answers are assuming the order will be consistent and `:attrib4` will always be second/last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `serialize` in your model, then you'll be able to return the hash correctly:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :attrib0
end
```

Then the following should return the hash

```
hash  = @model.attrib0
# => {:attrib1 => value, :attrib2 => [{:attrib3 => value}, {:attrib4 => value}]

# now to access attrib4 you need to get the attrib2 array,
# then grab attrib4 by its index:
hash[:attrib2][1]
# => {:attrib4 => value}

# or to get the value:
hash[:attrib2][1][:attrib4]
# => value
```

The above however can get quite complex and ugly, which is why I recommended creating another model for these attributes instead.

Comment: In my model I serialized :attrib0 - also I edited my question regarding the accessed attribute

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). Here's how it can be:

```
class Example
  has_one :attrib0

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attrib0
end

params = { :attrib0 => { :attrib1 => value1, 
  :attrib2 => [ {:attrib3 => value3}, {:attrib4 => value4} ] }
}

example = Example.create(params[:attrib0])
example.attrib0.attrib1 #=> value1
example.attrib0.attrib2 #=> [ {:attrib3 => value3}, {:attrib4 => value4} ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't use nested attributes for technical reasons

Answer (score 0):

*Using Ruby technique only:*

```
h = {:attrib0 => {
  :attrib1 => :value1,
  :attrib2 => [
    {:attrib3 => :value2},
    {:attrib4 => :value3}
    ]
}}

p h[:attrib0][:attrib2].last[:attrib4] #=> :value3
```

Comment: this seems to work, except that I have to type p h.attrib0[:attrib2].last[:attrib4] thanks!